# Replacing select columns in a data frame with new columns of equal length

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which I will call "abs.data" that contains 265 columns (variables). I have another data frame which I will call "corr.abs" that contains updated data on a subset of the columns in "abs.data". Both data frames have an equal number of rows, n=551. I need to replace the columns in "abs.data" with the correct observations in "corr.abs" where the column names match. I have tried the following

```
abs.samps <- colnames(abs.data) #vector of column names in abs. data

corr.abs.samps <- colnames(corr.abs) #vector of column names in corr.abs

abs.data[,which(abs.samps %in% corr.abs.samps==TRUE)] <- corr.abs[,which(corr.abs.samps %in% abs.samps==TRUE)] #replace columns in abs.data with correct observations in corr.abs where the column names are the same
```

When I run the left and right side of the last line of code R pulls the right columns, but it fails to replace the columns in abs.data with the correct data in corr.abs. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the common column names using

```
comm_col <- intersect(colnames(abs.samps), colnames(corr.abs))
```

eg. you find X2 is the common column

you can first drop the columns, in this case X2 from abs.samps that you do not want using subset

```
 x<-subset(abs.samps, select = -X2)
```

then you can just add the new column (eg. column name X2)to the new data frame

```
 y<-cbind(corr.abs$X2,x)
```

Comment: I actually wanted to replace the columns in abs.samps with the columns in corr.abs that have matching column names.

Comment: Thanks that works, I was hoping for a more automated way of doing it, but can't find one.